# How do I get data from an anonymous type that's been converted to an object?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a delayed function manager so that you can call `TimeManager.DelayedCall(uniqueid, delay, action)` to make `action` get invoked in `delay` seconds. However, I'm running into some trouble. Here's the code so far.

```
private static Dictionary<string, object> delays = new Dictionary<string, object>();

public static void Think(float dt)
{
        timestep = dt * timescale;

        time += timestep;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kv in delays)
        {
            if (time > kv.Value.ourtime)
            {
                kv.Value.action();
            }
        }
}

public static void DelayedCall(string id, float delay, Action a)
{
        delays[id] = new { ourtime = time + delay, action = a };
}
```

This code doesn't compile. Because I'm converting the anonymous type from the `DelayedCall` function to an `object`, I cannot get the variables `ourtime` and `action` from it in the `Think` function! Does anyone know how to fix this, or how to do this in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT Corrected some details here.  See comment by Matti Virkkunen below.

Your anonymous type only has scope in the method where you create it. You cannot get the properties in the think function, because once you cast it into the object <s>and save it in the dictionary the properties you set are gone.</s> you cannot cast it back to the original type created by the compiler, so you cannot access the properties you set except indirectly via reflection.

Why do you need to use anonymous types and object type at all?

Based on the code posted I would just create a DelayData object that has all the properties you need to set, create and store instances of DelayData in the dictionary, and then use that object directly from the dictionary.

Comment: Sorry for yet another post of the same thing - there were no answers when I started typing.

Comment: That's the way it goes. The clearest post usually wins the prize and not the fastest post.

Comment: I guess I was too lazy to make a separate class for this, but I guess I'll have to do it now anyway! Cheers!

Comment: The properties aren't "gone". Casting an object only changes the current type of reference you have to it, and doesn't change it in any way. The properties can still be accessed via `dynamic` or reflection, although that loses type safety.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well... You could always use reflection to access the fields in your object, but that's slow, and potentially ugly (although that last point is subjective). A cleaner version would involve dynamic objects (but then you lose type safety).

But why must you absolutely use an anonymous type? Can't you juste write a small wrapper `class` or `struct`, and then use that instead of `object` in your dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection:

```
Action a = () => { Console.Write("Hello"); };
object o = new { ourtime = DateTime.Now, action = a };

DateTime ourtime = (DateTime) o.GetType().GetProperties()[0].GetValue(o, null);
Action action = (Action) o.GetType().GetProperties()[1].GetValue(o, null) ;
```

But it would be much cleaner to create a new type to hold these values i.e. `TimedAction` with two properties `Time` and `Action`

Answer (score 1):

I'd get rid of the AnonymousType. It just makes things unclear, and the possibility for dorking up the values in the dictionary by adding the wrong type. I also added some Linq, and the use of List.ForEach.

```
public class Thing
{
    public double ourtime;
    public Action action;
}

public class Program
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Thing> delays = new Dictionary<string, Thing>();

    public void Think(float dt)
    {
        timestep = dt * timescale;

        time += timestep;

        var actions = delays.Where(d => time > d.Value.ourtime).Select(d => d.Value.action).ToList();
        actions.ForEach(a => a());
    }

    public void DelayedCall(string id, float delay, Action a)
    {
        delays[id] = new Thing { ourtime = time + delay, action = a };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a tiny class with two properties and use that instead of an anonymous class. Another option is to switch to dynamic objects, and give up type safety.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a new type

```
class DelayAction
{
    float OurTime;
    Action a;
}
```

and change to

```
private static Dictionary<string, DelayAction> delays = new Dictionary<string, DelayAction>();
```

and

public static void DelayedCall(string id, float delay, Action a)
{
        delays[id] = new DelayAction{ ourtime = time + delay, action = a };
}

Answer (score 0):

I make extension method ToDictionary

```
object anonymous = new
{
    Id = 1234,
    Password = "pwd",
};

var dictionary = anonymous.ToDictionary();
```

and extension method was below.

```
    public static IDictionary<string, dynamic> ToDictionary<T>(this T target, bool exceptDefaultValue = false)
        where T : class
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
        }

        IDictionary<string, dynamic> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>(System.StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(target))
        {
            object value = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(target);

            if (exceptDefaultValue == true)
            {
                if (value == null || value.Equals(propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.DefaultValue()) == true)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            dictionary.Add(propertyDescriptor.Name, value);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
```